# How to add multiple users in telegram channel using ImportChatInviteRequest in python

Tags: telethon

I'm having trouble adding multiple users to the telegram channel by using the invite link ImportChatInviteRequest in python.

I have tried the telethon documentation about ImportChatInviteRequest but it only adds me to the channel and since I'm already a member of the channel and the Admin I don't want to add myself.

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
updates = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest('AAAAAEHbEkejzxUjAUCfYg'))
```

I have tried the above code but like I said it only add me and I am the admin. Whenever I run this program this error shows up

```
Error: The authenticated user is already a participant of the chat (caused by ImportChatInviteRequest)
```

what I want to know is that is it possible to add multiple users using ImportChatInviteRequest and can you show it to me?